# How to make business validations on fields in editable Table?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Here is the deal: I have a Table who uses a BeanItemContainer of "MyBean". "MyBean" is not really relevant, it contains only 1 String and 2 Date objects.
But the user must be allowed to change theses values for each instance of MyBean in my container.

To do that, it's easy, just do myTable.setEditable(true). Or a little bit more complex, create a Table.ColumnGenerator who returns a Field (add a ValueChangeListener to push the new value inside the bean).
With the Table.ColumnGenerator, I'm also able to add specific validations for each Field, that's great!
The purpose of this is to render the Field in "error mode".

But there is something I'm not able to do: make my business validations after the user clicks on the "Save" button and retrieve the corresponding field to call the method setComponentError(...).

Only basic validations can be done (integer only, max value, date time range, ...) but for more complex validations (business requirements) I don't know...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom validators by implementing [Validator](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Validator.html) interface and in them implement custom business logic.

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    void validate(Object valueToValidate) throws Validator.InvalidValueException {
        //Your Business logic
    }

}
```

Comment: I know but it's always limited. My table contains resources used from X time to Y time (1 row of my table). I have to validate that no resources are used at the same time. Only one on a time. But I have found another way to do that: my table contains Fields elements. :-)